# Fitting a linear combination of two arrays with variable coefficients to another array

Tags: regression

Suppose I have two arrays A1 and A2, which I know corresponds to array A3 as follows:

A3 = a×A1+b×A2

I'm trying to find a way to optimize the parameters a and b without iterating manually through a predetermined set of a and b. I have been looking at some linear regression theory, but I'm not sure what the best approach is to tackle this problem.

Comment: This is a completely standard regression problem.  Since you say you're aware of that, what is the difficulty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that $A_1$, $A_2$ and $A_3$ are matrices of arbitrary size and that $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, and that the difficult part of the question is how to transform $A_3=a·A_1+b·A_2$ in more standard expression that could be solved straightforward as a regression problem.

The first step is to transform $A_i$ in column matrices (that is, matrices with just one column). You can do this by stacking the coefficients in the way you prefer - but the same way for all $A_i$. Let's call $B_i$ the stacked form of $A_i$.

Now, let's take $B_1$ and $B_2$ and place them in a 2 columns matrix - the first column will have the coefficients of $B_1$ and the second one the coefficients of $B_2$ - and call this matrix $B$.

Now your original expression is:

$$B_3=B·\bigg(\begin{array}{c}a\\b\end{array}\bigg)$$

If $B$ (and $B_3$) have more than 2 rows, in general this equation will be incompatible and we use the regression approach. We want to find $a$ and $b$ that minimise squared $\epsilon$ in:

$$B_3=B·\bigg(\begin{array}{c}a\\b\end{array}\bigg)+\epsilon$$

And that is just an standard regression problem. Its solution in matricial form is:

$$\bigg(\begin{array}{c}a\\b\end{array}\bigg)=(B^T·B)^{-1}·B^T·B_3$$

Comment: Thank you very much for this clear explanation! Although, from the moment you state: "now your original expression is:", I assume with B1 you mean B3?

Comment: Fixed. ***This is a dummy sentence just to make the system let me post this comment****